# REGEXP_SUBSTR-Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, substr

How do I get the all words after the 4th forward slash from below using REGEXP_SUBSTR?(using oracle sql)

/plt/v1/v2/shipment-mgr/grids/shipoppre

all I need is

shipment-mgr/grids/shipoppre

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column name is col1:

```
select substr(col1, instr(col1, '/', 1, 4) + 1)
from ...
```

You DON'T need regexp; whenever you can use standard substr and instr, it's better, since regexp is slower.

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( your_column, '^(/.*?){3}/' )
```

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR( your_column, '^(/.*?){3}/(.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 )
```

Or using `INSTR` and `SUBSTR`:

```
SUBSTR( your_column, INSTR( your_column, '/', 1, 4 ) + 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @MT0 - In your last solution you must repeat your_column as the first argument to INSTR, right?

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, that's what I get for writing while rushing for a plane.